# Unsuccessful read from serial port

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to read the data from serial port and plot the graph.

I'm getting the warning of Unsuccessful read:The specified amount of data was not returned within the Timeout period.

Kindly help me to get over this warning

I've added mu code for the reference.

I'm getting the error at data(i) = fread(s)

```
close all;
clc;
clear all;

s = serial('COM5'); 
ll=0; 
s.InputBufferSize = 1; 
try
    fopen(s);
catch err
    fclose(instrfind);
    error('Make sure you select the correct COM Port where the Arm is connected.');
end

%while 1
Tmax = 20; 
figure,
grid on,
xlabel ('Time (s)'), ylabel('In Amplitude'),
axis([0 Tmax+1 -10 255]),

Ts = 0.002;
i = 0;
data = 0;
t = 0;
tic 
while toc <= Tmax
    i = i + 1;

    data(i) = fread(s)
    if data(i)>200
         ll=1+ll;
    end

    t(i) = toc;
    if i > 1
        T = toc - t(i-1);
        while T < Ts
            T = toc - t(i-1);
        end
    end
    t(i) = toc;
        if i > 1
        line([t(i-1) t(i)],[data(i-1) data(i)])
        drawnow
        end


    %data=0;
end

%end

img = screencapture(0, 'Position', [0 0 1270 1023]);
imwrite(img,'output.jpg');
fclose(s);
```

Comment: What is the error message? What are you trying to load in from the serial poer?

Comment: I meant to say serial port*